# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 1)) in VGG16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pre-trained-model, vgg-net

I am trying to do some prediction of cifar10 dataset by using Keras.applications.VGG16 pre-trained model. And when I am trying to fit the model I'm getting this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/2872537315.py in <module>
      7     epochs=EPOCHS,
      8     callbacks=callbacks,
----> 9     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
     10 )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1024, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1083, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 284, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2176, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5681, in binary_crossentropy
        labels=target, logits=output

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 1)).
```

Here are my codes I am sharing for better understanding my problem.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

height = x_train.shape[1]
width = x_train.shape[2]
channel = x_train.shape[3]

BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 2
NUM_CLASSES = 10
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4
MOMENTUM = 0.9

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, NUM_CLASSES)

base_model_VGG16 = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(height, width, channel))

for layer in base_model_VGG16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model_VGG16.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
predictions = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model_VGG16.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("save_at_{epoch}.keras"),
]

model.fit(
    x_train,y_train,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

Can anyone please help me, where I am making the mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: (1). don't mix tensorflow.keras with old keras. (2). may be use tf.keras.utils.to_categorical - there's no issue in your code side, it works (tested with tf 2.11.)

Comment: I changed np_utils.to_categorical() with tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(). And tried to run the program again. Now, I got this error.

ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 10, 10)).


Can you please tell I am doing the wrong sir? Thanks.

Comment: Run your above code in colab.

Comment: Thanks. It is fixed now. I changed y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES) with y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train). And now the logits and labels are matching. Thanks a lot.